# Вывод результата работы скрипта в браузер

Tags: python, apache, centos

Доброго дня. Возникла, казалось бы, простенькая задача: вбить в браузер некую сслыку, получить в ответ результат работы python-скрипта. Площадка: CentOS 6.4, httpd (так уж получилось). Прочитал много, голова закипела. Первое, что хотелось бы узнать, какой из модулей предпочтительней использовать (mod_python, либо через mod_wsgi и т.д.) и для каких решений? Обязательно ли привлекать для таких задач фреймворки типа Django? Может я чего-то вообще не понял, на самом деле уже каша в голове. Может кто-то ткнет носом в адекватный мануал или покажет свои конфиги httpd.conf. Или объяснит принцип (где должны лежать скрипты, как вызываться), остальное сам найду. Надоело уже отлавливать ошибки модулей и отказы доступа.

Comment: сразу  возникает вопрос, апач в вашей конфигурации просто необходим или просто не знаете альтернатив ?

Comment: необходим, там модули для авторизации некоторые прикручены. но как бы не принципиально, объясните на примере nginx...

Comment: я не питонщик, но деплоил большой клиентский проект, там был nginx+beanstalkd не знаю насколько это оптимально, щас проснется кто-нить расскажет.

Comment: все-равно спасибо, и эту связку учтем. я и сам в питоне не силен, некоторое наследие осталось, надо разобраться. а чтобы делов не натворить неосознанных, решил посоветоваться.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, пока остановился на mod_wsgi (нашел реализацию связки и с apache и с nginx), решающую роль здесь скорее сыграло наличие в стандартных репозиториях. mod_python, как я понял, вообще больше не развивается, а остальные нужно собирать, либо подтягивать из сторонних репов. Но может что и пропустил.

Без использования фреймворков, для того чтобы вывод появился в браузере, необходимо просто скрипт написать определенным образом, что-то типа:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/html')])
    return ['<html><body>Hello!</body></html>\n']
```

Будем разбираться дальше.